Big Data to implement Inverted Search Index
Which db/cloud service provides easy way to implement inverted search index?
I have ids of tables and ids of its columns and need to find all the tables with having the following set of columns. I need periodically add/remove tables.

Example Implementation with Elasticsearch:
Index Creation:

Create an index for tables with a mapping that includes the table ID and a nested array of column IDs.

Document Ingestion:

Add documents representing each table with its associated columns.
Search Query:
Use Elasticsearch’s query DSL to find tables containing the specified set of columns.
json

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

# Initialize Elasticsearch client
es = Elasticsearch()

# Create an index with a mapping
index_name = 'tables'
mapping = {
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "table_id": {"type": "keyword"},
            "columns": {"type": "integer"}  # Ensure this matches the type of your data
        }
    }
}
es.indices.create(index=index_name, body=mapping)

# Add a document
doc = {
    "table_id": "table_1",
    "columns": [1, 2, 3]
}
es.index(index=index_name, id=1, body=doc)

# Search for tables containing specific columns
search_body = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"term": {"columns": 1}},
                {"term": {"columns": 2}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
response = es.search(index=index_name, body=search_body)
print(response)

This approach should allow you to efficiently search for tables by columns and manage periodic updates to the table data.
